Can't connect to my MySQL host server on my local machine
Lately, I have tried to connect to my MySQL server on the local machine through letting it host my computer IP address. Several things that I have done:

I use ipconfig to check my computer's IP4 address is 172.24.32.1, my IP and port are set to 172.24.32.1:3306 for this MySQL database.
The user I used was the first 'spark', and for show grants, I granted full rights to this user.
I have already disabled the firewall. I have overridden some outbound rules so it can accept connections from all IPs pointing to port 3306 of my computer.
In MySQL's my.ini file, I commented out the bind-address line with the skip-connecting line
I also make sure that my MySQL server is running through net start MySQL80

After everything is done, I still can't connect. Is there any step I'm missing, below is the image for the user and its privileges:
enter image description here
The place that I have used to connect to my MySQL server is through Databricks and Google Colab, none of them works
Please give me concepts or details on which part that I should double check or as if I was missing some crucial parts to allow remote access to my MySQL server

I don't really understand, but I think you can restart the service and machine: because I solved a similar problem last time, sometimes simply restarting the MySQL server and client computer can solve the connection problem.
